# Is it possible to set PercentPositivePattern in Windows UI?

Tags: windows, number-formatting

In an application that is internationalized, I have code like this:

```
_comboBlah.Items.Add(pct.ToString("P0", formatInfo));
```

where formatInfo is normally from the CultureInfo for the current UI language (which might well be different from the CurrentCulture. I was surprised that when "en" is the UI language (and incidentally also the CurrentCulture), the value of formatInfo.PercentPositivePattern is 0 (meaning that the number and percent sign will be separated by a space). Since this is not the *normal* way to format percentages in English (U.S.), I went into Regional and Language Settings to see if I could see why it was set this way and change it to format without the space (PercentPositivePattern = 1). I couldn't find any way to set this in the Windows UI. Is there a way? Anyone know why this is the default? (It's not the default in Excel.) Is there any way around this besides changing it programmatically when "en" is the UI language? Is there any hope that MS got it right for other built-in locales?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer at all? I'm wondering the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: No, I could not find a way. I ended up treating it as a localization issue (our project uses [L10NSharp](https://bitbucket.org/sillsdev/l10nsharp)) and did it like this:
`var pctFmt = LocalizationManager.GetString("CommonToMultipleViews.PercentFormat", "{0}%");
_sliderVolume.TooltipFormat = string.Format(pctFmt, "{0:F0}");`

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this. Somehow my Windows 10 system was set to PercentPositivePattern=1 and I want the default 0 back...